# Node.js Oracle Database Connection Pool Size

Tags: node.js, oracle, connection-pooling, node-oracledb, fastify

I implemented a connection pool (poolMin=poolMax=10) with node-oracledb and i saw a difference of up to 100 times especially in case of few users like 10. Really impressive. I also increased UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE like 4 + poolMax. At this point I could not understand somethings.

```
process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE = 4 + config.pool.poolMax // Default + Max
```

NodeJs works as Single Thread (with additional 4 threads those none of them are used for network I/O). So when i use a pool with 10 connections, can Single Thread use all of these connections? Or isn't it Single Thread with these settings anymore? Because i added 10 more to UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE. I would be grateful to anyone who explained this matter.

Btw, I wonder if using a fixed number pool like 10 would cause a problem in case of too many users? For example, if the number of instant users is 500, we can reach 5000 instant users on certain days of the year. Do I need to make a special setting (e.g. pool size 100) for those days or will the default be enough?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 3):

When you do something like `connection.execute()`, that work will handled by a Node.js worker thread until the call completes.  And each underlaying Oracle connection can only ever do one 'thing' (like execute, or fetch LOB data) at a time - this is a fundamental (i.e. insurmountable) behavior of Oracle connections.

For node-oracledb you want the number of worker threads to be at least as big as the number of connections in the connection pool, plus some extra for non database work.  This allows connections to do their thing without blocking any other connection.

Any use of `Promise.all()` (and similar constructs) using a single connection should be assessed and considered for rewriting as a simple loop.  Prior to node-oracledb 5.2, each of the 'parallel' operations for `Promise.all()` on a single connection will use a thread but this will be blocked waiting for prior work on the connection to complete, so you might need even more threads available.  From 5.2 onwards any 'parallel' operations on a single connection will be queued in the JavaScript layer of node-oracledb and will be executed sequentially, so you will only need a worker thread per connection at most. In either version, using `Promise.all()` where each unit of work has its own connection is different, and only subject to the one-connection per thread requirements.

Check the node-oracledb documentation [Connections, Threads, and Parallelism](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#numberofthreads) and [Connection Pool Sizing](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#conpoolsizing).

Separate to how connections are used, first you have to get a connection. Node-oracledb will queue connection pool requests (e.g. `pool.getConnection()`) if every connection in the pool is already in use.  This provides some resiliency under connection spikes.  There are some limits to help real storms: [`queueMax`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbqueuemax) and [`queueTimeout`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbqueuetimeout). Yes, at peak periods you might need to increase the `poolMax` value.  You can check the [pool statistics](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpoolmonitor) to see pool behavior.  You don't want to make the pool too big - see the doc.

Side note: `process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` doesn't have an effect in Node.js on Windows; the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` variable must be set before Node.js is started.